# Keeping Track of a Daily Quota (Auto-Expiring Increment) - Redis or Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, redis

The basic problem is very simple: 
There is a running list of insertions for every time something happens (let's say number of times a file has been downloaded) - the Idea would be to keep a running total of the number of times it has been downloaded but to expire each addition to the running total 24 hours from then (So the total itself shouldn't reset to zero, but rather the downloads older than 24 hours should fade out of it).

(Also If there is a way to auto-expire the `increment` action in `Redis`, someone please interrupt me right now)

The peculiar situation is that there is a small application that already utilizes `Redis` to keep track of a few repeatedly updated values, and `MongoDB` with `Pymongo` for long-term storage. I am about to implement a daily quota on certain functions, which can be tracked in either `Redis` or `MongoDB`.

Redis has a problem that it's basically flat, so in order to keep track of each download expiring (rather than the total), one has to create separate items: 
i.e.

```
cache.set('filename1.downloads.action_234612', {'downloads': 1)
cache.expire('filename1.downloads.action_234612', 86400)
```

Then to figure out if the number of download has reached a daily limit I can sum the count of objects in the cache identified by 'user1.votes.action_*'.

The second alternative as I see it would be to throw the votes in a pymongo collection, with timestamps - and then ignore the items, where `time.time() - download_timestamp > 86400` (not SQL just because MongoDB is already being used).

I know there is probably a much faster way to do this on a lower level - but I'm not sure if the performance difference would justify finicking with it. (At least it seems conceptually possible to do so without indexing the item set, and operating only on the uppermost item of a stack).

Note if the server goes down or otherwise, there is an integrity check that will run at the start and re-total the number of times a file has been downloaded (or whatever increment one is tracking).

Comment: to what precision do you need to satisfy this "within past 24 hours"?  And what sort of volume are you talking about here (in terms of files being downloaded and average downloads per file per 24-hours?)

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you whether you'd be better off using MongoDB or Redis, but here's how I would do it with Redis.

For each counter, i.e. downloaded file, keep a sorted set. The members of the sorted set should represent download actions and their scores are the timestamp of the action. When updating the sorted set trim old items from it and set an expiration time for the entire set.

The workflow for adding a download to the counter would be something like the following in pseudo-Python (note that redis-py switches the order of member and score):

```
r.zadd('filename1:downloads', 'action_234612', time.time())
r.zremrangebyscore('filename1:downloads', '-inf', time.time()-86400)
r.expire('filename1:downloads', 86400)
```

You'd probably want to use a MULTI/EXEC block for the above or, alternatively, use a server-side Lua script for it.

Now that the hard work is done, obtaining the current downloads count for a file (i.e. during the last 24h) is a simple matter of [`ZCOUNT`](http://redis.io/commands/zcount) on the key (you may also wish to trim it here as well):

```
downloads = r.zcount('filename1:downloads', time.time()-86400, time.time())
```

Answer (score 1):

Lacking reputation means that I can't comment on Itamar's perfectly valid answer.

Having done something similar very recently, I only have two minor changes to the previous solution. 
When adding an item to the sorted set, I (and it seems others as well) did not have a need for the member-item and initially implemented it similar to Itamar's solution by using a unique counter item.

After a while I changed it to:

```
r.zadd('filename1:downloads', time.time(), time.time())
```

to make member and timestamp the same (unique) value.

As the check whether an action was over quota always happened at the time when a user tried to initiate the action, I made sure that the trimming (zremrangebyscore) covered the entire time window I was interested in (86400) and used zcard() instead of zcount().

Again in pseudo code:

```
def try_download(r, sorted_set_key, timestamp=time.time(), limit=1000, window=24 * 60 * 60):
    # trim current set
    r.zremrangebyscore(sorted_set_key, '-inf', timestamp - window)
    # how many items are there in the set?
    count = r.zcard(sorted_set_key)
    # too many?
    if count >= limit:
        return False
    # add new download
    r.zadd(sorted_set_key, timestamp, timestamp)
    # expire after window seconds
    r.expire(sorted_set_key, window)
    # return True meaning download allowed
    return True
```

There is a race-condition between zcard and zadd, which can be addressed via WATCH/MULTI/EXEC or LUA scripting.

Answer (score 0):

A version using mainly pandas.Series.shift. It imposes a temporal resolution of one minute but could be generalized to any time resolution.

It relies on a journal whose size is the **entire time window**. For a 24 hours time window, it is ok (24*60 values so 1440). But for a larger time window, it could take quite some memory (43200 values for 30 days)...

The journal is shifted every time a record is made in order to forget recordings that are too old.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd # must be at least version 0.24

class QuotaExceededError(Exception): pass

class TimeWindowQuota():
    """
    Check if a quota has not been exceeded during a past given time window.

    IMPORTANT: the time window resolution is in minute. So any two records 
    occuring within the same minute of the current date will be counted as 
    one record.
    """

    def __init__(self, time_window_minutes, limit):
        """
        Args:
            - time_window_minutes is a positive integer 
            - limit is a number above which to raise QuotaExceededError
        """
        self.limit = limit
        self.journal = pd.Series(np.zeros(time_window_minutes))
        self.head_date = None # will be initialize at 1st record

    def record(self, quantity=1, date=None):
        """
        Record a quantity for a given date. Quantities recorded outside the past
        time window will be forgotten.

        IMPORTANT: the time window resolution is in minute. So any two records 
        occuring within the same minute of the current date will be counted as 
        one record.

        Args:
           - quantity : a number to record (can be negative)
           - date (datetime): date associated with the recording.
             Cannot be a date earlier than the previous call of record.
             Default is datetime.now().
        """
        if date is None:
            date = datetime.now()

        if self.head_date is not None:
            assert(date >= self.head_date) # cannot record in the past
            dt = (date - self.head_date).total_seconds() / 60.0
            self.journal = self.journal.shift(int(dt), fill_value=0.0)

        self.journal.loc[0] += quantity
        if self.journal.sum() >= self.limit:
            raise QuotaExceededError()

        self.head_date = date

if __name__ == '__main__':

    tracker = TimeWindowQuota(time_window_minutes=24*60, limit=100)
    tracker.record(quantity=90, date=datetime(2020,4,24,20,20,0))
    tracker.record(quantity=50, date=datetime(2020,4,25,20,20,0))
    tracker.record(quantity=20, date=datetime(2020,4,26,10,50,0))
    tracker.record(quantity=29, date=datetime(2020,4,26,20,19,0))
    # This will raise a QuotaExceededError:
    tracker.record(date=datetime(2020,4,26,20,19,0))
```